# How to Update google apps standard Edition user's profile through my Own application I.e. Using API

Tags: gdata-api, gdata

I've Gone through the gdata apps profile API. But, it's not useful for standard edition users.
So, I would like to know that is it possible to update the google apps standard Edition user's profile using api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no API is available that does the same for the googleapps standard edition.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible through the administrator of user domain only to modify/update the profile.

Your client application can use the Profiles Data API to retrieve the profiles of users in a Google Apps domain and to modify them on behalf of an administrator.

Profiles cannot be inserted or deleted, since every user is considered to have a profile, even if it is blank. Your client can populate a profile using an update operation. It can send an update operation with no content to clear existing profiles.

see for more detail [here](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/profiles/developers_guide_protocol.html)

Comment: by the term Profile Data API you mean : http://code.google.com/apis/apps/profiles/developers_guide_protocol.html??
If yes then, as I've already mention in the question it's useful only for  Google Apps Premier, Education, and Partner Edition domains, and cannot be used for accessing or editing Google Apps Standard Edition or Gmail profiles. While I want to access Google Apps Standard Edition user's profile..!!